# Google EOLed my Chromebook Flip C302 (CAVE), so I installed coreboot and ChromeOS Flex. Now I can't boot from SD slot. USB boot works, any ideas?

Tags: linux, chromebook

Google decided my Asus Chromebook Flip C302 (CAVE) was EOL. Fine. I flashed coreboot (Thanks, MrChromebox,tech!) and installed Chrome OS Flex.

Before, I spent most of my time booting Linux from the microsd card slot. As with a Raspberry Pi, it is not fast, but let me keep multiple OS options on different cards for versatility. (Great for a device that turns from an OK laptop to a so-so tablet.)

However, though coreboot sees my microsd slot and lets me select it for boot, it ignores my choice and boots Chrome OS from EMMC anyway. Needless to say (he said anyway), these cards worked fine before. I installed Linux to a new card, same thing.

The machine boots fine from a USB (thanks, Ventoy!) but that's a pain and uses 50% of my USB ports (100% when charging), so I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to restore the functional boot from microsd.
Incidentally, I've enabled Dev mode on Flex (and keep re-enabling it after every update) if that suggests any ideas.

This is a decent Celeron box with a great touchscreen, 8GB RAM, but only 32GB storage -- which didn't bother me when I was booting from 256GB microsd cards -- so I'd hate to lose it. Any ideas?

Comment: If the main issue using up a USB port, use a µSD adapter (~US5) and small USB hub. Another option would be to install Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#1-overview) or other Linux OS, which is able to run both native Linux apps and Windows app in wine, which might allow booting from µSD.